# Horizontal scrollbar in Firefox caused by #fb-root

Tags: css, facebook, sdk, horizontal-scrolling

I'm creating a responsive design but have run into a problem where the Facebook Javascript SDK code's `div#fb-root` is causing a horizontal scrollbar when the browser width is less than 590px. I've tested this on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, but the issue only occurs in Firefox.

Should I just set `div#fb-root` to `display:none` or is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** As requested, the code below is how I'm loading the SDK. When I don't load the SDK, the horizontal scrollbars disappear.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: Great post! I was suffering this problem too and now I've got a fix!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `display: none` is completely OK, since that `<div>` is not used for showing anything, it's a placeholder where all the FB scripts can be loaded into and appended to your page

Comment: I have also just struggled with this. What's up with endless array of blog posts writing about FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow, .setSize, setting overflow:hidden on body element etc etc, when this simple hide Just Works (tm)? What are those other horizontal scroll bar hide approaches about, they just don't know any better?

Comment: This answer is incorrect according to FB docs which say that the fb-root div should not be hidden.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/#fbroot

Answer (score 3):

Setting `display:none` made the scrollbar disappear, but when I used FB.ui(), no dialog showed.

I managed to solve it by wrapping #fb-root in another div:

```
<div id="fbdiv" style="width:0px;height:0px"><div id="fb-root"></div></div>
```

placed at the end of the body tag.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note this .fb-root also breaks sticky footers implemented with `html { height: 100%; } body { display: table; height: 100%; }` and footer `footer { display: 'table-row'; width: 100% }`

Facebook should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with hiding the fb-root div arises when you want to make use of the apprequests API call. This places the dialog for sending app requests to friends in the div. If the div is hidden, the request dialog will never be shown. I found out about this the hard way.

You could just try setting the width of the div on page load or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same problem and tried a slew of different CSS tricks to fix it.

Setting the width of fb-root or container divs doesn't fix the problem.  Neither does any form of overflow:hidden.  The only thing that has worked for me is indeed making fb-root hidden as Zoltan said.  After doing this I tested the button several different ways and I am not seeing any broken functionality using with this method at least for myself.

If their script button is going to break people's sites FB really should be fixing this issue on their end.

NOTE: Firefox is the only browser this problem comes up with.

Comment: as this does not directly answer the question, you should have posted it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Here (and in Firefox only) it just showed two small empty "iframe-ish" windows in the middle of my page.

I solved using `display: none`, but Facebook should definitely fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do:

```css
#fb-root {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999em;
}
```

and not have it cause a horizontal scrollbar. If for some reason you don't want to use `display: none;` you could then move it back with JavaScript/jQuery if you really need it shown.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your css

```
#fb-root {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Normally, when people share code, they give a little bit of explanation. It would be great if you did that too. Thanks.